# How to structure Multiple object and array of JSON in java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

This is JSON file. I want make java can produce like this json. Just ignore the value, What i want is the structure of the json.

```
{
  "Car": [
    {
      "CarId": 123,
      "Status": "Ok"
    },
    {
      "CarId": 124,
      "Status": "ok"
    }
  ],
  "Motor": [
    {
      "MotorId": 3,
      "DriverId": 174
    },
    {
      "MotorId": 3,
      "DriverId": 174
    }
  ],
  "Bus": [
    {
      "BusId": 8,
      "Status": 3
    },
    {
      "BusId": 9,
      "Status": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my java code.

```
JSONObject motorObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject busObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject carObject = new JSONObject();

JSONArray motorArray = new JSONArray();
JSONArray busArray = new JSONArray();
JSONArray carArray = new JSONArray();

motorArray.put(motorTracks.getJSONObject());
busArray.put(buss.getJSONObject());

try 
{
    motorObject.put("Motor",motorArray);
    busObject.put("Bus",busArray);

    carArray.put(MotorObject);
    carArray.put(stepObject);

    carObject.put("Car",dataArray);
} catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is :

```
{
  "Car": [
    {
      "Motor": [
        {
          "MotorId": 0,
          "DriverId": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Bus": [
        {
          "BusId": 0,
          "Status": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For value, it's okay, just ignore the value, but what i want how can i get structure like the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code and Enjoy :)

```
private void createJsonStructure() {

    try
    {
        JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray carArr = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("CarId", "123");
            jsonObject.put("Status", "Ok");
            carArr.put(jsonObject);
        }
        rootObject.put("Car", carArr);


        JSONArray motorArr = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("MotorId", "123");
            jsonObject.put("Status", "Ok");
            motorArr.put(jsonObject);
        }
        rootObject.put("Motor", motorArr);


        JSONArray busArr = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("BusId", "123");
            jsonObject.put("Status", "Ok");
            busArr.put(jsonObject);
        }
        rootObject.put("Bus", busArr);

        Log.e("JsonObject", rootObject.toString(4));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try. Can i know why u put value 4 in rootObject.toString(4) ?

Comment: It will display the ooutput in logcat in Json like structure.

You can try with value 4 and also without 4 and can see the difference.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Comment: yes adding the null value to Json doesn't accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONObject motorObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject busObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject carObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject wholeObject =new JSONObject();

    JSONArray motorArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray busArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray carArray = new JSONArray();

    motorArray.put(motorTracks.getJSONObject());
    busArray.put(buss.getJSONObject());
    carArray.put(car.getJSONObject());

    try
    {
        wholeObject.put("Motor",motorArray);
        wholeObject.put("Bus",busArray);
        wholeObject.put("Car",carArray);
        System.out.println(wholeObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I try put jsonObject.put("BusId", null); ... But the output not show BusId

Comment: jsonObject wont consider the null values for a key.instead try put empty String  ""